# ngModel no realiza el binding - Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo en el HTML este `<select>`:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Selecciona un grupo</option>
    <option [(ngModel)]="seleccion.grupo" value="valor de prueba">grupo 1</option>
    <option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
</select>
```

Y este el objeto, en el .ts:

```
  seleccion = {
    grupo: null,
    usuario: null
  }
```

Quiero elegir una opción, y que guarde el valor dentro del objeto `selección`. Pero no me lo esta modificando, he probado de varias formas pero no entiendo por que no actualiza el campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando mal `ngModel`:

- En la etiqueta `select` es donde se usa `ngModel`
- En las etiquetas `option` puedes usar `value` o `ngValue`.

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo como:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="seleccion.grupo">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Selecciona un grupo</option>
    <option value="valor de prueba">grupo 1</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```